# Selecionar dados de duas tabelas

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldades em relacionar dados de duas tabelas.

Tenho duas tabelas. Tabela Posts e a tabela Favoritos.

```
Tabela Favoritos:
id, id_utilizador, id_post
1   109            20 
2   200            20
3   105            104   
4   109            150
-------------------------------------------
Tabela Posts:
id, id_post, id_owner, titulo, discricao
1   20       123            qqcoisa  qqcoisa
2   150      321            xxxxx    xxxxx   


--------------------------------------------
```

Eu queria apresentar numa página os favoritos do utilizador id = 109, incluindo o titulo e a descrição da tabela dos posts?

```
utilizador post titulo descricao
109        20   qqcoisa qqcoisa
109        150  xxxxxx  xxxxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penso que o que queres fazer é um INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT Favoritos.id_utilizador, Posts.id_post, Posts.titulo, Posts.descricao 
FROM Favoritos 
INNER JOIN Posts ON Favoritos.id_utilizador=Posts.id_utilizador;
```

No `SELECT` são colocados os campos que pretendes obter, não esquecendo o nome da tabela a que o campo pertence.

No `FROM` colocas o nome das tabelas que queres juntar e a maneira como elas vão ser juntas (`INNER JOIN`, `OUTER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` ou `RIGHT JOIN`). Depois dizes onde elas vão ficar juntas, ou seja, o elemento em comum nas duas tabelas.

Ainda podes adicionar um `WHERE` para colocar condições, sendo que tal como no `SELECT` tens de colocar o nome da tabela e o nome do campo (Ex: Posts.id_post = 20).

Comment: Obrigado @Rui Cardoso , já conhecia esse INNER JOIN, mas à tua custa pude perceber melhor como funciona. Obrigado. Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente seria isso.

Usando PDO:

```
$buscar = $suaConexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN favoritos ON posts.id = favoritos.id_utilizador");
//Nessa query sera buscado tudo na tabela posts que tenham um ID igual a um id_utilizador da tabela favoritos

$buscar->execute(); // Executa a busca
$linha = $buscar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Retorna o resultado como array associativo
foreach($linha $resultado): // Inicia o loop para pegar todos os dados
echo $resultado['id_owner'];
echo $resultado['titulo'];
echo $resultado['descricao'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa usar um `INNER JOIN`, que seleciona colunas de duas tabelas segundo uma condição que relaciona dados das duas tabelas:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use o INNER JOIN, caso queira trazer todos os campos da outra tabela que você esta relacionando use o LEFT JOIN.