# Como ligar tabelas que estão em bases de dados diferentes?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Gostaria de saber como posso ligar duas tabelas que estão em bases de dados diferentes por forma a achar dados que são semelhantes nas duas tabelas.

Por exemplo, podemos ter a tabela **Lista de compras por fazer** e tabela **Lista de compras feitas**, para no fim **auto criar uma tabela dos itens que constam na mesma tabela** deixando de lado os itens que não foram comprados.

Comment: Utilize o `JOIN` do MySQL para mesclar dados de tabelas diferentes.

Answer (score 7):

### Unindo tabelas com `UNION` e `JOIN`:

Você usa **`UNION`** na "Vertical", para relacionar conforme a pergunta, em linhas separadas:

> [Search em várias tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230365/70)

> [Qual é a diferença entre UNION e UNION ALL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153496/70)

> [Buscar em tabelas diferentes sabendo de qual veio o resultado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163399/70)

Você usa **`JOIN`** na "Horizontal", para relacionar duas tabelas na mesma linha:

> [Selecionar dados de duas tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81814/70)

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70)

### Aplicando a bases de dados diferentes:

Como você falou que se tratam de **bases de dados diferentes**, você deve prefixar o nome das tabelas com suas respectivas bases (aplicável tanto a `UNION` quanto `JOIN`):

```
SELECT tabelaA.campo1, tabelaB.campo2 FROM baseA.tabelaB JOIN baseC.tabelaD ON <condicao>
                                           -----              -----
```

**E se por acaso as tabelas possuirem o mesmo nome nos DBs diferentes?**

Aí você usa um *alias* em cada uma:

```
SELECT aliasX.campo1, aliasY.campo2
FROM baseA.tabela AS aliasX
JOIN baseC.tabela AS aliasY ON <condicao>
```

**E se as bases de dados estiverem em servidores separados?**

Uma das soluções seria resolver o problema na linguagem cliente (PHP no caso), simplesmente executando duas *queries* e mostrando os resultados em seguida (ou filtrando e mostrando com operações de *array* por exemplo).

Dependendo da aplicação, pode usar `FEDERATED TABLES`, mas precisa tomar cuidado com a eficiência da aplicação:

```
create table t1 (
a int,
b varchar(32))
ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='mysql://user@hostname/test/t1'
                 -- aqui vão os dados do outro servidor --
```

Mais detalhes aqui:

> [Como faço para usar MySQL Federated?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31293/70)

> [The FEDERATED storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

> [Wikipedia - MySQL Federated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Federated)

Comment: ficou muito bom. Só uma observação para ele: A depender da situação, ele teria que testar resolvendo o problema no back-end (como foi citado na resposta) ou plataformas como `ElasticSearch`, `Memcached` etc. Talvez ele vá perder [performance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-usagenotes.html) com tabelas federadas.