# Como fazer o select de duas tabelas no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu sei que isso deve ser uma pergunta fácil, mas sou iniciante:

Tenho essas 3 tabelas no meu banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, a tabela comprados é onde fica armazenado o cpf do usuario que adquiriu o curso e salva o id do curso. Acho que isso está certo,

Daí, o que eu quero fazer é um select que retorne o curso que o usuario está cadastrado.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Pesquise sobre `join`. Já adianto que armazenar CPF como inteiro não é uma boa ideia. Por mais que ele pareça um número, é, na verdade, um texto formado por caracteres numéricos. Para verificar isso, basta pensar que `011 111 111 11` é diferente do valor `11 111 111 11`. Quando representado como inteiro, o zero a esquerda é descartado.

Comment: Tem uma série de links respondendo à sua pergunta nesta postagem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267808/70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, suas tabelas não estão otimizadas e você vai ter problemas mais para a frente com nomes, referências, etc., como por exemplo, usar o CPF como um id de usuário na tabela compras. O mais indicado seria usar um auto-increment para um ID sequencial e então usá-lo.

Pense que ao usar o CPF você poderá ter problemas com as buscas (fácil de errar a digitação, terá que tratar casos de cpf's inválidos, etc.).

Também acho que não ficou legal você permitir a tabela comprados com os 2 campos setados em **null**, assim o que você armazenaria em um caso de duplos nulls?

Mas como você é iniciante, então isso é normal. Não se preocupe, [aqui vai um link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join) para você aprender algumas coisas básicas referentes a cruzar dados entre tabelas e que vão fazer toda a diferença.

Enquanto isso, esse é o código que você precisa:

```
select cursos.nome, usuarios.nome
from cursos, usuarios, comprados
where comprados.usuarios_id = usuarios.cpf
and  comprados.cursos_id = cursos.id;
```

Comment: Tem como descrever melhor por quê usar um inteiro em auto incremento seria melhor que usar o CPF como chave? O argumento de que é fácil errar na digitação e validação m pareceram bem fracos, pois qualquer número é fácil de errar a digitação e a validação se faz necessária em qualquer situação, sendo chave ou não.

Comment: No caso a tabela comprados é null os dois campos, pois só pode ter um registro nela no caso de compra efetuada, mas eu ainda estou montando, e obrigado pelo link e a resposta. Ajudou muito..