# Consultas SQL com multiplas tabelas

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

estou estudando SQL e precisava fazer uma consulta, que para mim é mais complexa.

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
Tabela Ativo: id, tipo_ativo
Tabela Carteira: id, nome..
Tabela Movimento: id, ativo_id, carteira_id
```

Preciso retornar uma lista de "**Carteiras**" que possuam "**Movimentos**" com "**Ativos**" de um determinado tipo, que seria definido na clausula WHERE.

Como ficaria essa consulta? Me ajudem por favor

Comment: Já tem muitas postagens sobre isso no site, pesquise por SQL e JOIN. Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441, mais links na resposta aqui, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/267808 e tem muito mais.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você poderá utilizar a seguinte estrutura de query:

```
   select * from Carteira 
        inner join  Movimento on Carteira.id = Movimento.carteira_id
        inner join  Ativo  on Ativo.id = Movimento.ativo_id
```

**OBS: Você tem que ficar atento que se as tabelas Carteira, Movimento e Ativo possuirem algum atributo com o mesmo nome o (*) asterísco não poderá ser utilizado na query.Sendo necessário  qualificar os nomes dos atributos que desejar projetar na consulta**

Explicando a query

```
 inner join  Movimento on Carteira.id = Movimento.carteira_id
```

Define que o atributo de relacionamento entre as tabelas Movimento  e Carteira são os atributos id da Carteira e o atributo carteira_id  do Movimento

```
inner join  Ativo  on Ativo.id = Movimento.ativo_id
```

Define que o atributo de relacionamento entre as tabelas Movimento  e Ativo são os atributos id da tabela  Ativo e o atributo ativo_id  da tabela  Movimento.

Pelo que entendi a  tabela Movimento é uma entidade de relacionamento. Desta forma é necessário estabelecer essa estrutura para trazer a relação de Ativos com Movimentos.